# How to efficiently build a document fragment

Tags: javascript, performance, reflow

I have around 10,000 rows to render. I read that using document fragments is the most efficient way to create document elements and append them to the DOM because a document fragment won't incur reflows of the layout to be triggered whilst you are appending to it.  It sounds great in principle but my UI locks up for ~10 seconds whilst the elements are being added to the fragment.

My current code:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for( var bay_name in self.results )
{
  if( locations = self.results[bay_name] )
  {
    locations.forEach( function( location )
    {
      var volume      = parseFloat( location['volume'] ).toFixed(5);
      var node        = document.createElement('tr');

      node.innerHTML += '<td>' + location['product_id'] + '</td>';
      node.innerHTML += '<td>' + location['length'] + '</td>';
      node.innerHTML += '<td>' + location['width'] + '</td>';
      node.innerHTML += '<td>' + location['height'] + '</td>';
      node.innerHTML += '<td>' + volume + '</td>';
      node.innerHTML += '<td>' + location['stock'] + '</td>';

      frag.appendChild( node );
    });
  }
}

self.data_container.appendChild( frag );
```

I assume the reason things are lagging is because `createElement` is instatiating a new node in memory for every row in the table, but if I move `var node = ...` where I build the frag it will only append one node to the table.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: Does code call `var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()` 10000 times?

Comment: Nope it only calls it once

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. I'm not asking about spawning new threads, I know javascript is a single threaded event driven language.   I'm asking why I'm incurring the thread to block whilst I'm applying to a document fragment.  I already tried implementing my own deferred approach by rendering 50 elements every 100ms but I still had intermittent blocking on the main thread.

Comment: Did you experience blocking using approach at Answer at linked Question?

Comment: No, but the fundamental thing here is I am not using jQuery.  I want to understand why this is happening

Comment: jQuery is not necessary to implement the pattern. Note the `setTimeout()` call between pushing elements to an array.

Comment: Oh yeah I experienced blocking by doing that with my chunking approach

Comment: _"Oh yeah I experienced blocking by doing that with my chunking approach"_ Not certain how that would be possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'll take another look and will report back if I'm still facing issues

Comment: Ok, so if I load everything into a document fragment in chunks of 250 with a 150ms delay on the promise resolving the thread doesn't block until it appends the fragment to the page, at which point it blocks for around 3 seconds

Comment: Almost off topic comment but did you considered pagination + search-box? As a user, a table of 10000 rows is just... unusable. So when it locks the UI, as a developer, I choose not to show everything and give a pretty and convenient way to access the info.

Comment: Pagination is where I'll end up going with this but I know its possible to render 10,000 rows efficiently, I was just interested at having a go at running my own implementation. I know that using a non paginated view is a bad idea